# Importing pyodbc in app.py causes azure web app to fail

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-web-app-service, pyodbc

[image: Container error]

[image: Web-app]

requirements.txt

```
click==8.1.3
Flask==2.2.2
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.2
pyodbc==4.0.35
Werkzeug==2.2.2
```

app.py

```
import pyodbc
from flask import Flask, render_template

#def get_db_connect():
#    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:servername.database.windows.net,1433;Database=Dev-testing;Uid=username;Pwd={supersecurepassword};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;')
#    return conn

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
#    conn = get_db_connect()
#    assets = conn.execute('SELECT * FROM chosen_table').fetchall()
#    conn.close()
    return render_template('index.html')
```

If I comment out the import it produces the base page and works. But having that import causes the container to crash. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm needing to establish a DB connection to an Azure SQL instance. I have tried to follow tutorials but nothing seems to work.

Comment: How are you building pyODBC when installing ? Seems like it's just not installed.

Comment: I use github actions to build and deploy. I allowed Azure to create the workflow.

Comment: Please add the build script (or markup file) and the logs of the build you used above.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I have installed pyodbc in my local
**pip install pyodbc**

[image]

> I'm needing to establish a DB connection to an Azure SQL instance. I have tried to follow tutorials but nothing seems to work.

According to the above comment I created Azure SQL Database in portal.

[image]

Then, I created a python application to connect Azure SQL server DB by importing **pyodbc**

```
from  flask  import  Flask, render_template

import  pyodbc

  

app = Flask(__name__)

  

server = 'tcp:***.database.windows.net'

database = '****'

username = '****'

password = '*****'

  

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';ENCRYPT=yes;UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)

cursor = cnxn.cursor()

  

@app.route('/')

def  index():

cursor.execute("select current_timestamp;")

row = cursor.fetchone()

return  'Current Timestamp: ' + str(row[0])

  

if  __name__ == '__main__':

app.run()
```

I Started running my application in local, Its working fine in local.

[image]

Then I deployed my application in Azure web app.

[image]

After deploying to Azure Web App also Its running fine.

[image]